# Data class Kotlin to Java Class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, data-class

I have a kotlin data class and I'm trying to call it from Java method.

```
data class Item  (
                @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var var1: Long? ,
                @ColumnInfo(name ="var1") var var2: Long){}
```

From Java , I'm trying to save a list of Item so I need to instance Data class.  I don't understand how I can do it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instantiating a `data class` is not different from instatiating a "normal" Kotlin class.

From your Java code, you instantiate it as if it were a Java class:

```
Item item = new Item(1L, 2L);
```

Just for reference, a `data class` is a `class` that automatically gets the following members (see [documentation here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)):

- `equals()`/`hashCode()` pair;
- `toString()` of the form "MyClass(field1=value1, field2=value2)";
- `componentN()` functions corresponding to the properties **in their order of declaration**; this can be useful for [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html#destructuring-declarations), such as:

  ```
  data class Item(val val1: Long, val val2: Long)

  fun main(args: Array<String>) {
      val item = Item(1L, 2L)
      val (first, second) = item
      println("$first, $second")
  }
  ```

  This will print: `1, 2`
- `copy()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your data class will be like this :

```
       data class Item  (@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var var1: Long?,
            @ColumnInfo(name ="var1") var var2: Long);
```

From Java you can create create object like this:

```
  Item item=new Item(1L,2L);
   long firstValue=item.getVar1();
   long secondValue=item.getVar2();
```

If you want to create instance in kotlin it will be like:

```
   val item=Item(1L,2L);
    val firstValue:Long?=item.var1;
    val secondValue:Long?=item.var2;
```

Comment: Don't need semicolons in your kotlin examples.

Comment: Yes Semicolons are optional in Kotlin.